# Text mining match in Python

Tags: python, text-mining

I have one column called `A` and one column called `B` where column `B` is a more detailed description of column `A`, for example:

| A | B | want |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red apple | I love RED apple | 100% |
| organic orange | I love citric fruit | 0% |
| BANANA lover | I have 2 banana | 50% |

Basically the algorithm is if we have all values of `A` in `B` then give 100% match, if similar then give 80%, and if no value of `A` is found in `B` then 0%.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: a method like word2vec or bert may help from the area of NLP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand from your question, you are trying to compare sentences on word level, but it seems like you are interested in finding the number of words in sentence A that are contained in sentence B (not te intersection itself)

So you could use something very simple (as a first approach)

Try:

```
def simmilar(s1,s2):
    l1 = s1.split()
    l2 = s2.split()
    l1 = [s.lower() for s in l1]
    l2 = [s.lower() for s in l2]
    
    n = len(set(l1))
    
    return len(set(l1) & set(l2))/n 



df.assign(result = df.apply(lambda x: simmilar(x["A"], x["B"]), axis = 1))
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Julio. This is perfect and worked as needed.

Comment: Can you please help how to export the result in excel. This is what i have done and giving me error writer = pd.ExcelWriter('mypath\Datamining_v1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.assign.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()

Comment: sure, assuming your pandas data frame is named df, try: ```df.to_excel("write_your_path.xls")```it is very like likely that it will raise an error since it needs a library to be install, so just install that library (I do not remember the name right now) and try again with ```df.to_excel("write_your_path.xls")```

Comment: it worked in export part but the  "result" didnot come in the table.. it ahs just A and B col

Comment: the complete code would be something like: ```df.assign(result = df.apply(lambda x: simmilar(x["A"], x["B"]), axis = 1)).to_excel("your_path.xls")```

Comment: works like a charm Julio. Thank you so much. one last favor.. can you recomend soem courses related to these task?

Comment: At the very beginning I found this channel really helpful on understanding pandas basics and some introductory concepts with scikit learn.  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnVzApLJE2ljPZSeQylSEyg

Comment: Thank you so much Lulio. I will follow your path

Comment: Julio is there a way to investigate 0% deeper. For example we have A =  Sweet Pineapple   B = Pine swe    now showing 0% what we want is   IF the first 3 words  matches with first 3 words in any sequence  then we give 100% in this example because all words of A first letter matches with first 3 letters of B . If possible, create a separate COl called result 2 so that based on our first logic they are 0% based on our second logic (this) its 100%. Please advice

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for"

```
palabras = ['red apple', 'organic orange', 'BANANA lover']
frases = ['I love RED apple', ' I love citric fruit', 'I have 2 banana']
for frase in frases:
   for palabra in palabras:
       i =0
       word = palabra.split()
       for w in word:
           if(w.lower() in frase.lower()):
               i +=1
       print(str(i/len(word)*100))
```

Output:

```
100.0,
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
50.0
```